Error in unserialize(node$con) : MultisessionFuture (future_lapply-8) failed
I try to process multiple tab-delimited-textfiles in R in parallel with library(future.apply).If I use 100 textfiles it runs fine.
If I use 1000 textfiles it gives this error:
Error in unserialize(node$con) : 
  MultisessionFuture (future_lapply-8) failed to receive results from cluster RichSOCKnode #8 (PID 30716 on localhost ‘localhost’). The reason reported was ‘error reading from connection’. Post-mortem diagnostic: No process exists with this PID, i.e. the localhost worker is no longer alive. The total size of the 7 globals exported is 87.57 KiB. The three largest globals are ‘process_file’ (48.16 KiB of class ‘function’), ‘...future.elements_ii’ (26.07 KiB of class ‘list’) and ‘%>%’ (7.47 KiB of class ‘function’)

or this error:
Error: No such device or address

Each textfile is approx 5000KB.
I have 256GB RAM and a 32 core processor.
OS is Windows 11.
I do not run any other processes at the same time.
I have tried different settings for num_parts and workers in my code below although the errors persist.
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(future.apply)

start.time <- Sys.time()

# Define the test function
process_file <- function(file_path) {
  
  # Print the basename of the file being processed
  print(paste("Processing file:", basename(file_path)))
  
  # Read the data
  data <- suppressMessages(read_tsv(file_path, col_names = TRUE, show_col_types = FALSE))
  
  # some example processing:
  return( tibble(
    Name = c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie"),
    Age = c(25, 30, 35),
    Score = c(85, 90, 95)
  ))

  # Combine all results into a single dataframe
  bind_rows(result)
}
    
# Specify the directory containing your files
file_directory3 <- "J:/test"
file_paths3 <- list.files(file_directory3, pattern = "*.txt", full.names = TRUE)

# Split file paths into parts
num_parts <- 128
split_file_paths <- split(file_paths, cut(seq_along(file_paths), breaks = num_parts, labels = FALSE))

# Configure future for parallel processing
plan(multisession, workers = 16) # Adjust workers according to your CPU cores

# Apply the function to each part in parallel and combine results
results <- future_lapply(split_file_paths, function(file_part) {
  part_results <- lapply(file_part, process_file)  # Apply `process_file` to each file
  bind_rows(part_results)  # Combine tibbles within this part
})

# Combine all results into one tibble
combined_result <- bind_rows(results)

# Shut down future plan
plan(sequential)

Any idea what can be the cause and how to solve it?
I can split my data in parts of 100 although this is no guarantee it will function for every part of 100 files I suppose.
Thanks a lot!
EDIT:
I have tried to use 4 workers (pc has 32 cores). This gives the error below:
Error in unserialize(node$con) : 
  MultisessionFuture (future_lapply-4) failed to receive results from cluster RichSOCKnode #4 (PID 12944 on localhost ‘localhost’). The reason reported was ‘error reading from connection’. Post-mortem diagnostic: Failed to determined whether a process with this PID exists or not, i.e. cannot infer whether localhost worker is alive or not. The total size of the 7 globals exported is 166.14 KiB. The three largest globals are ‘...future.elements_ii’ (104.64 KiB of class ‘list’), ‘process_file’ (48.16 KiB of class ‘function’) and ‘%>%’ (7.47 KiB of class ‘function’)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
3: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
4: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
5: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
6: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Using callr (see answer HenrikB) gives this error:
Error in file(file, mode) : cannot open the connection


I did find that my Rtemp directory (which is located on a specific partition of my harddisk) was completely full. It is full of vroom-files (from readr) created during the last days. Probably due to testing the script above, which opens many files with readr. After deleting all files from Rtemp the code runs lightning-fast with r-future!

The part of the error message that says:
The reason reported was ‘error reading from connection’.

tells us that the main R session is no longer able to communicate with the parallel worker.  The:
Post-mortem diagnostic: No process exists with this PID, i.e. the localhost worker is no longer alive. ...

part strongly suggests that the parallel worker, that is, its R process, is no longer running. Something caused it to terminate abruptly. There can be many reasons for this, but it's unlikely it has to with the future framework per se.
One readon could be that you are running out of memory and the operating system decides to kill one or more of your parallel workers. Running out of memory is more likely to happen the more parallel workers you run. You could try with fewer parallel workers to see if it makes a difference. You can also monitor the memory use in the operating system's process manager.
You could also try using more, but smaller chunks, e.g. 10-times smaller chunks:
future_lapply(..., future.scheduling = 10.0)

This should result in a smaller memory footprint per parallel worker. Another thing you could try together with the latter is to use:
plan(future.callr::callr, workers = n)

instead of plan(multisession, workers = n).
You could also try to see if it makes a difference with a subset of the files.
There could also be other reasons for R processes to crash, e.g. low-level bugs in some code you're using. Looking at the code, I don't think that's the case here.

@ HenrikB You pointed me in the right direction since it was indeed a memory issue. Thanks a lot for your help!
